# How to recover Notepad++ multiple instances?

Tags: notepad++

I have enabled multiple instances in Notepad++ and when my second instance was closed or crashed:

1. it does not automatically restart when I restart Notepad++
2. it is not listed in the recently closed instances
3. I cannot find where the backup is stored

Is there any way to recover that data and enable restarting all instances?

Comment: The same happens if I reboot Windows: just one of the two Notepad++'s opens, and I find nowhere the tabs of the other one.

A poor solution is to move the tabs from one Notepad++ to the other and then close the empty one before rebooting Windows.

Comment: If I got this right, there are no very good solutions. Did I? This is 11 years old. https://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331754/thread/1748deb5/